# VBA ReadLine Error while reading from a file

Tags: excel, runtime-error, excel-2003, filesystemobject, vba

I am using Excel 2003 & I have following code in my macro.

```
Dim fs, a, retstring
Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set a = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\file.txt", ForReading, False)
Do While a.AtEndofStream <> True
  retstring = a.ReadLine
Loop
a.Close
```

When I execute this, it shows

> "Runtime Error:5"
>
> Invalid Procedure Call or argument at OpenTextFile

Comment: Define the constant ForReading = 1.  Check out the code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722196/what-is-dim-fso-myfile-filename-textline-in-vba).

Comment: @deusxmach1na : Thanks for that. it works. Please put it as answer so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 2):

You must define the constant ForReading first.  And you may as well define the constants ForWriting and ForAppending while you're at it.

```
Dim fs, a, retstring
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\file.txt", ForReading, False)

Do While a.AtEndofStream <> True
   retstring = a.readline
Loop
a.close
```

Answer (score 2):

fso is considered slow. Here is a faster method to read a text file.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim i as Long

    '~~> Read the entire file in 1 go
    Open "C:\MyFile.Txt" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        Debug.Print strData(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool! Do you have a link to a tutorial on using For Binary?  It looks interesting.

Comment: @deusxmach1na: There are plenty on the web. Here is the first one I came across... http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/reading-and-writing-binary-files-visual-basic

Comment: @SiddharthRout The link you have given is for VB. will that work in VBA too ?

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i did like this.

```
    Dim fs, a, retstring
    Set fs = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set a = fs.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\228319\Desktop\file.txt", 1, False)
    Do While a.AtEndofStream <> True
    retstring = a.readline
    Loop
    a.Close
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using Excel 2007 and got the same problem with near the same code snippet. Enabling 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime' should solve it (Main menu >Tools > References), it worked for me.