# identifiy lanaguage from ASP file

Tags: programming-languages

```
<%

account = "001"
password = "xxx"

Set httpReq = Server.CreateObject(""MSXML2.XMLHTTP)
httpReq.Open
httpReq.Send

If Error <> "" Then 
 ...
Else 
Dim Address
...
End IF

%>
```

What Language is this? it is from an ASP file on a HTTP webserver.
A html page is using Xml Http Post to send data across to it, of which I require the service it provides

Comment: It looks a lot like Visual Basic for Applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Wikipedia page on ASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Server_Pages):

> Programmers write most ASP pages using VBScript, but any other Active Scripting engine can be selected instead with the `@Language` directive or the `<script language="manu" runat="server">` syntax.

Since there doesn't seem to any `@Language` directive, and since the code contains the `Dim` keyword, [which indicates it is some Basic dialect](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1033507/41071), this indeed looks like it's [VBScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript).